# Azure AD B2C Signup/Signin userflow not returning "Is User new" claim. (NextAuth used to signup/login)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, next-auth

In B2C user flows, I have checked the box for claim "User Is New" to be returned as part of the token.

I'm using NextJs and NextAuth with JWT for managing authentication and it works otherwise. I need to determine if user is new to trigger an external API call.

From documentation I have tried events to get this info like so:

```
events: {
    signIn: async ({user, account, profile, isNewUser}) => {
      console.log(`isNewUser: ${JSON.stringify(isNewUser)}`);     
    }
  },
```

isNewUser is always undefined.
I have also tried logging token, account and profile to see if there is new user information anywhere in jwt callback like so

```
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
      if (account) {
        console.log(token)                          
        console.log(account)                          
        console.log(profile)                          
      }

      return token;
    },
```

None of the objects contain information about new user. How can I get information about new user?

There is an alternative approach I could do. There is an external API attached to this application. Since Azure AD B2C is handling all user information, by default I do not have any users in my own application database. This is what I am trying to do here, if user is new I would register that user into my own database as well. So during signin I could call my own API to check if this user is in databse and create it if needed. But that would make 1 extra API call which I could avoid if I could determine if user is new beforehand.

**EDIT:**
Everything works ok! Info will be in token, problem for me was that I was testing with same email when creating new user. I deleted user from B2C and signed up again ... I then found out the "Delete permanently" functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

newUser is only returned when the user signs up.

Definitely works with custom policies.

Comment: I double checked now with creating a "completely" new user and it does work, info is in token!
What I did before to test was that I deleted a user from Azure AD B2C and then remade antoher user with same email, this seems not to trigger a new user.

Do you know how can I remove a user completely so that for testing purposes I can reuse same email.

Comment: I now found the "Delete permanently" functionality